# Mail merge from excel to word - source data is coloured, not printing coloured in word doc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, fonts, colors, mail-merge

I have an Excel file where several cells contain coloured, bold font.
I need the output into the Word doc to be coloured, bold font.

The first time I experimented I got coloured output in the Word doc, but now I'm not and I can't work out what I have done wrong.

Please help
Thanks
Berrill

Comment: There really not much to go here. Sample data and the details of what you've tried would be useful. If you could [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1652733/edit) to provide it, it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to macropod's thread about Mail Merge, you can read *Conditionally Format Mailmerge Output* and *Conditionally Shade Table Cells in the Mailmerge*:

http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html